# C# Cannot use Streamwriter on a txt file in C# Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, arrays, resources, streamwriter

I am currently working on an assignment for school where I am trying to write a 2D string array into a text file. I have the array and know its working fine however every time I try to read the file into Streamwriter I get "System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'". I am relatively new to C# and I have no idea how to fix this.

This is my code. I just need to know how to write my 2D array into the text file without getting this error. Thanks, all and any help is much appreciated!

```
    // This line under is where the error happens
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Harvey_Norman.Properties.Resources.InventoryList))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    sw.Write(InventoryArray[i, j] + " ");
                }
                sw.Write("\n");
            }

            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at your `using` statement and tell us what `Harvey_Norman.Properties.Resources.InventoryList` contains.

Comment: This is what is in the file
`Jeff[Testing 123[30[50]
John[Testing 456[34[52] 
Deb[Testing 789[10[80]`

Comment: You cannot write to an embedded resource, you must use a file name.  Like "c:\foo\bar.txt"  Why you are trying to use an embedded resource is very hard to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `Harvey_Norman.Properties.Resources.InventoryList` is a resource in your project that is typed as a string-- and the value of that string is not a valid path for your operating system.

`StreamWriter` will either take a string, in which case it expects to open a file with the path of that string; or it will take a stream, and you can write to that stream.  It looks like you are trying to do the former; but you need to check the value of that resource to see if it is a vaild path.

Comment: I have this in the file

`Jeff[Testing 123[30[50]
John[Testing 456[34[52]
Deb[Testing 789[10[80]`

And I am trying to write over this file

Comment: But what is `Harvey_Norman.Properties.Resources.InventoryList`?  Is that a string that is the name of a file that content?  Or is it that content itself.  It almost certainly isn't a `File`.  It may be a resource that the compiler reads from a file, which means it is really the contents of the file as far as C# sees it. You need to pass the name of a file to the `StringWriter` constructor, not the contents of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to construct a `StreamWriter` with an invalid file path.

Also, if you're just writing text out, you can use `File.CreateText()` to create a `StreamWriter`, for example:

```
var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var writer = File.CreateText(tempFilePath))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (j > 0)
                writer.WriteLine(" ");

            writer.Write(InventoryArray[i, j]);
        }

        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The `using` will automatically flush and close the file, and dispose the `StreamWriter`.